# Service Reference Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, service-reference

I am trying to recreate at WPF application as a Windows 8 Application.  The Application uses a service reference to an service provided by a third-party developer.  In the WPF application I have a service.Search method that takes three parameters.  When I add the service reference in my Windows 8 Project I get a service.SearchAsync method.  The problem is that the new SearchAsync method only takes two parameters.

Where does this code generation happen?  How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that this was by design in Window 8 Apps.